# $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&-\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$ eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra

> How do I compute the eigenvector of $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&-\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$?

$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&-\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta\\x\sin\theta -y\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$

The I got this system of equations:
${x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=\lambda x\\x\sin\theta -y\cos\theta=\lambda y}\implies$

$\det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda-\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&-\lambda-\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}=0\implies -\lambda^2+\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=0\implies\lambda=1 $

**Questions:**

**1)** How do I compute $\lambda$?

**2)** Is it possible to get a simple value for the given matrix $A$?

Comment: Your second entry of the product is wrong. Are you familiar with the fact that $\lambda$ is a root of $\det(A-\lambda I)$? Typically, all textbooks write it the line after the definition of "eigenvalue".

Comment: Which is also the reason why no one ever says "*the* eigenvalue of $A$".

Comment: When calculating eigenvalues with the determinant formula, the $\lambda$s always occur along the diagonal. The result will become a second degree polynomial in a polynomial of the complex exponential function.

Comment: Geometrically, this is a counterclockwise rotation of $\theta$ radians composed with a reflection about the horizontal axis.  So, except for specific values of $\theta$, e.g. $\theta = 0$, expect complex eigenvectors since rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ preserve nothing.

Comment: "How do I compute $\lambda$"?  Solve a quadratic equation.

Comment: (edited comment) Oops, I misread and thought that you have a rotation matrix. This one is easier. Didn't you get the equation $-\lambda^2+1=0$? Aren't the solutions $\lambda=\pm1$.

Comment: @KajHansen A rotation (of a plane) composed by a reflection is a reflection. Basically because a composition of two reflections is a rotation. This one is a reflection. When $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$ we reflect w.r.t. a coordinate axis. When $\theta=\pi/2$ the reflection is w.r.t. the line $y=x$.

Comment: Ohhh, you are correct.  I see it now @JyrkiLahtonen.  I've never been the best at visualizing.  Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to fix a lot of math errors before you can do this right.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} - \lambda\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \right) = (\cos\theta-\lambda)^2 + \sin^2\theta \\[10pt]
= {} & \lambda^2 - 2\cos\theta + 1 = 0 \\[10pt]
&\text{if and only if } \lambda = \cos\theta \pm i\sin\theta.
\end{align}

Comment: Check the characteristic equation again, please. The eigenvalues are $\lambda=\pm1$. The determinant of this matrix is $=-1$, which is also the product of the eigenvalues. Geometrically this linear transformation is an orthogonal reflection w.r.t. a line forming an angle $\theta/2$ with the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just below the highlighted equation, you have $\sin \theta y$, which is wrong; the $y$ should be next to the $\cos \theta$ (preferably before it, to improve readability).
2. In the determinant just about "Questions", the $\lambda$ in the second line should be in the second column, not the first, so that the bottom row reads $-\sin \theta ~~~ \lambda + \cos \theta$.

If you continue from there, you have some hope of correctly computing $\lambda$.

Comment: Please check my edit!

Comment: The second line of your last matrix has sine and cosine swapped. You really need to actually do the algebra right if you want to get anywhere.

Comment: Could you please check the answer I provided?  Thanks!

Comment: Why is there a $-\lambda$ in the lower right of your matrix? I reiterate: you have to do the algebra right; that's the first step.

Answer (score 1):

To hand-calculate the eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrices, I believe the best way is **not** to expand $\det(\lambda I-A)$, but to write down the polynomial $\lambda^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)\lambda + \det A$ directly. This is always more efficient and less error prone.

In your case, clearly $A$ has trace zero and its determinant is $-1$. Hence the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-1$ and the eigenvalues are $\pm1$.